# Initalize a child class via constructor requesting an array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I like to create a child class of a base class, but somehow I can not pass an anonymous stack array.

Base class constructor:

```
Shape::Shape(int origin[2], unsigned int vectorAmount, int vectors[][2]) 
    : origin{ origin }, VECTOR_AMOUNT{ vectorAmount }, vectors{ vectors } {}
```

Child class constructor:

```
I::I(int origin[]) : Shape(origin, 3, { {0,1},{0,-1} }) {
}
```

How could I handle it? Thanks for answers.

Comment: You could use an `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Arrays are not copyable.  Use a `std::array` or `std::vector` if you want to pass arrays into your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your C style members by STL-like containers, it will make your life much easier:

```
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
using Origin = std::array<int,2>;

class Shape {
public:
    explicit Shape(const Origin& origin, const Matrix& vectors = Matrix()) :
        origin(origin), vectors(vectors) {}

private:
    Origin origin{};
    Matrix vectors{};
};

class I : public Shape {
public:
     explicit I(const Origin& origin) : 
         Shape(origin) {
     }
};
```